# Transaction across multiple web services

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, jpa

I have quite a simple problem. I am rewriting very old app which is using direct access to database through DAO objects. There is no business layer (the code is not mine and is quite anti-code), so connection.setAutoCommit(false) is used for starting the transactions everywhere in the code. I had to rewrite the project because of security reasons, so it does not use database connection but webservices and hibernate/jpa on the J2EE server side (before it was standalone app, now app+j2ee). Simple - I just moved the DAO/VO objects to the webservice server and rewrote sql to hql and DAO in client replaced with webservice client.

But what to do with transaction code? Normally one transaction one webservice call. So I need some mechanism (parameter in webservices?) that could help me to reference to the same hibernate transaction across multiple webservice calls. Is it completely bad approach and should I just move the transactions in server code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use SessionBeans expose as JAX-RS services, and let them control the transactions.
If you need to have a transaction accross multiple webservice calls, just define a new webservice, also a EJB SessionBean that acts as a facade for the other calls.
I think is a bad practice to implement what you suggest (with referecing the same hibernate transaction), and I think it might not even be possible. Each WS call is a separate thread, at different moment in times, mixing transactions across threads is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I also think this is bad practice, because you usually build webservice methods that are coarse grained. So usually you are fine with one request per transaction.

I can understand your need but think about the downsides:

- How will you do a rollback about several transactions? This will introduce data inconsistencies, if not possible.
- If this is possible, your webservice won't be stateless anymore,
  which is commonly considered bad practice.
- This means, your API requests will be dependent on each other, so you have prerequisites for executing any of your request.

Have you tried to put your transaction within one request? This might help to re-structure and possibly enhance the code of your app.

Comment: I will do it other way - rewrite all transaction code and I will work with objects just in memory. If sucessful I will call the webservice. I tried to avoid this as it is at higher cost.. however.